# Ruby on Rails - Creating a Custom Route to #Show

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, custom-routes

I am still making my cookbook app, Im to the point to where I am building out the grocery list feature where you will be able to click a link "Add to Grocery List" and it will add all the ingredients from a given recipe to a grocery list on a new page, where you will be able to pull the page up on your smartphone while at the grocery store and mark off items as you go.

I am having some difficulty though with getting the correct route.

So I've got the grocery list appearing on the grocery#show page which is where I want it. I am to the point where I want to add the link to the recipe page so that a visitor can simple click the link, and they will be move to the grocery list.

Right now in order to get to the grocery list page for recipe #2 you must use the following url:

```
localhost:3000/recipes/2/groceries/1
```

Currently as you can see we must use the following route:

```
recipe_grocery GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/groceries/:id(.:format) groceries#show
```

Heres what I want it to be instead:

```
localhost:3000/recipes/2/groceries
```

I'm sure it quite an easy thing to do, but at the moment its escaped me. So any help you could provide, I would be forever grateful!

Here is what the bottom half of my rake routes currently looks like:

```
     recipe_favorites POST   /recipes/:recipe_id/favorites(.:format)     favorites#create
     recipe_favorite DELETE /recipes/:recipe_id/favorites/:id(.:format) favorites#destroy
    recipe_groceries POST   /recipes/:recipe_id/groceries(.:format)     groceries#create
      recipe_grocery GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/groceries/:id(.:format) groceries#show
             recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)                          recipes#index
                     POST   /recipes(.:format)                          recipes#create
          new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)                      recipes#new
         edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)                 recipes#edit
              recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)                      recipes#show
                     PATCH  /recipes/:id(.:format)                      recipes#update
                     PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)                      recipes#update
                     DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)                      recipes#destroy
              drinks GET    /drinks(.:format)                           recipes#index {:category=>"drinks"}
             entrees GET    /entrees(.:format)                          recipes#index {:category=>"entrees"}
               sides GET    /sides(.:format)                            recipes#index {:category=>"sides"}
            desserts GET    /desserts(.:format)                         recipes#index {:category=>"desserts"}
          appetizers GET    /appetizers(.:format)                       recipes#index {:category=>"appetizers"}
               about GET    /about(.:format)                            welcome#about
                    root GET    /                                       welcome#index
```

Here is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: :show
  get 'comments/index'

  get 'comments/create'

  get 'comments/show'

  get 'comments/edit'

  get 'comments/new'

  resources :recipes do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :show, :index, :new, :destroy]
    resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :groceries, only: [:create, :destory, :show]
  end

  get 'drinks' => 'recipes#index', :category => "drinks"
  get 'entrees' => 'recipes#index', :category => "entrees"
  get 'sides' => 'recipes#index', :category => "sides"
  get 'desserts' => 'recipes#index', :category => "desserts"
  get 'appetizers' => 'recipes#index', :category => "appetizers"


  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a route like this:

```
localhost:3000/recipes/2/groceries
```

You can update your `routes.rb` file with this:

```
resources :recipes do
  # other routes
  resources :groceries, only: [:create, :destory, :show, :index] # adding :index to the list
end
```

This, will give you a new route:

```
recipe_groceries GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/groceries(.:format)     groceries#index
```

Then, you will have the above route that will list all the `groceries` for a particular `recipe`, in your above case the `recipe` with `id` 2.

Comment: I can't believe I failed to realize that, thank you sir! It worked perfectly!